# How to scrape tr's with different column tags (1 = td and 2 = a within td)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem scraping a table. The table consist of the following rows, please refer to the html code below:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="hell" width="20%"> <b>1 : 0</b> </td>
    <td class="hell"> <a href="/speler_profiel/tjeerd-westdijk/" title="Tjeerd Westdijk">Tjeerd Westdijk</a> 1.</td>
</tr>, 
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="dunkel" width="20%"><b>2 : 0</b></td>
    <td class="dunkel"><a href="/speler_profiel/emiel-wendt/" title="Emiel Wendt">Emiel Wendt</a> 20.</td>
</tr>
```

Please note that each row consist of two columns. From the first column (td) I just want to scrape the text within the  tags so-> '1 : 0' & '2 : 0 '. From the second column I only want to scrape the text within the a tags so-> 'Tjeerd Westdijk' & 'Emiel Wendt'.

When I run my code (please refer to below) I get the text outside of the a tags (in the second column as  well) i.e. 1. & 20.

This is my code:

```
scores = []

for row in td1_7[start:end]:
scores.append([data.get_text(strip=True) for data in row.find_all('td')])

final_df = pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['Score','Playes'])

print(final_df)
```

this gives me the following output:

Score                           Playes
0  1 : 0                Tjeerd Westdijk1.
1  2 : 0                   Emiel Wendt20.

How can I remove the 1 and 20. in the column players?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of whole `<td>` with player name select `<a>` inside this column and get the `title` attribute:

```
data = '''<tr>
    <td align="center" class="hell" width="20%"> <b>1 : 0</b> </td>
    <td class="hell"> <a href="/speler_profiel/tjeerd-westdijk/" title="Tjeerd Westdijk">Tjeerd Westdijk</a> 1.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="dunkel" width="20%"><b>2 : 0</b></td>
    <td class="dunkel"><a href="/speler_profiel/emiel-wendt/" title="Emiel Wendt">Emiel Wendt</a> 20.</td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

rows = []
for col1, col2 in zip(soup.select('td:nth-of-type(1)'), soup.select('td:nth-of-type(2) a[title]')):
    rows.append((col1.get_text(strip=True), col2['title']))

print('{: <20}{: <20}'.format('Score', 'Players'))
print('-' * 40)
for row in rows:
    print(''.join('{: <20}'.format(d) for d in row))
```

Prints:

```
Score               Players             
----------------------------------------
1 : 0               Tjeerd Westdijk     
2 : 0               Emiel Wendt
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you for your message. It is not working for me. I get an error that select is not a attribute. When I rewrite the code on my example:                      
scores = []
for col1, col2 in zip(td1_7[start:end].select('td:nth-of-type(1)'), td1_7[start:end].select('td:nth-of-type(2) a[title]')):
 scores.append((col1.get_text(strip=True), col2['title']))

Comment: @Teunvdv `td1_7[start:end]` is `list`, and this list doesn't have `select` attribute. Call `select()` method on your BeautifulSoup object.

Comment: I did it a slightly different way. But thanks for your view on this case.